# Apps not opening

Tags: multiple-monitors, system-settings

Just installed Ubuntu for the first time (15.04), so I am new to this.
I've done research before asking, but couldnt find the answer.

I am not able to open any application, it seems that the application runs in the background, but not opening. Ex I can see firefox icon to the left, when I click on it, it runs, but I cant open the browser. Same happens with Vlc and steam etc.

What could be the solution?

(Processor Intel Core i3 CPU M 350@ 2.27GHz x 4
Memory 3,7GiB
Graphics Intel ironlake Mobile (Nvidia gt325)
Os type 64-bit)

Comment: Do you have a second screen, switched off?

Comment: The monitor on the laptop is broken, yes, so I have my TV connected to the pc. Should I set the setting to mirror screening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Normally", if you connect a second screen, the two screens make one combined virtual desktop. The fact that your laptop monitor is broken doesn't prevent that.

The applications you are running no doubt run correctly, but obviously they are running on your broken screen :)

What you need to do is actually *switching it off*  in System settings > Screens. Select the screen to switch off and select "off", like in the image:

[image]

Comment: That was exactly my problem! 
Thank you so much !

Comment: @Naveed85 Always a pleasure when a problem is solved, glad it works :)